# How to generate dynamic series data for highcharts?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using angular-highcharts for my project.I am used https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic this chart for my data.I have below data format.

```
[
    {
        "project": "train project1",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 58265
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "butify",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 3940
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "skler",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 563250
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "Internal Application",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 33325,
            "DAM": 328095
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "train2project",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 137215
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "CELLProje1",
        "hours": {
            "DAM": 488470
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "rangeselector",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 3015,
            "DAM": 71175
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "Android dev",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 99160
        }
    },
    {
        "project": "Web Application",
        "hours": {
            "AD": 72720
        }
    }
];
```

The values  inside "hours" will be one or more.I have added my fiddle tried so far.I struggling to form json for **series data**.Also I need form X -axis for the graph that should be in an array.
Ex:

```
categories: [
            'train project1',
            'beautify',
            'skler',
            'Internal Application',
            'train project2',
            'rangeselector',
            'Android',
            'Web Application'

        ],
```

X-axis formation will be right?

http://jsfiddle.net/harifrais/uxpvs8fw/34/

Comment: Can you show what format you want the data for the series?

Comment: Added my sample chart---column-basic..check the link at the start

Comment: I think I can see what you're trying to do... but there's going to be a big gotcha... you'll need to fill in `0`'s where the record doesn't exist in order for your categories to line up correctly. Do you have a separate list of all the keys (`AD` and `DAM` in this example)?

Comment: I don't have separate list.Thats the problem i have....

Comment: Updating answer... give me 5

Comment: okay wil give right now

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get data into this format

```
[ 
    {
       name:"series-name",
       data:[ ... ]
    }
]
```

But to use categories, there must be the same number of elements in each series as there are categories. And as every `hours` element in your input data does not contain all the same you need to do a little more work.

1. Get a distinct list of all the keys from `hours`
2. Loop over every element and use `project` as a category
3. Fill in zeros where any element does not occur in `hours`

So you can do this in a fairly simple 2-step process using `reduce` and `map`.

```js
var data = [{"project":"train project1","hours":{"AD":58265}},{"project":"butify","hours":{"AD":3940}},{"project":"skler","hours":{"AD":563250}},{"project":"Internal Application","hours":{"AD":33325,"DAM":328095}},{"project":"train2project","hours":{"AD":137215}},{"project":"CELLProje1","hours":{"DAM":488470}},{"project":"rangeselector","hours":{"AD":3015,"DAM":71175}},{"project":"Android dev","hours":{"AD":99160}},{"project":"Web Application","hours":{"AD":72720}}];

// get a distinct list of hour keys
var seriesData =  data.reduce( (acc, {hours}) => {
     Object.keys(hours).forEach(key => {
        if(!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
    })
    return acc;
},{});

// reduce the original data to get categories and series values
// filling in zeros where necessary
var result = data.reduce( (acc, {project,hours}) => {
   acc.categories.push(project);
   
   Object.keys(acc.seriesData).forEach(s => {
       acc.seriesData[s].push(hours[s] || 0);
   });
   
   return acc;
},{categories:[],seriesData:seriesData});

// shape the data to how highcharts wants it
var categories = result.categories;
var series = Object.entries(result.seriesData).map( e => ({
    name: e[0],
    data:e[1]
}));

console.log(categories);
console.log(series);
```

Here's an updated fiddle to show highcharts/your data: https://jsfiddle.net/u7opL2dw/2/

Comment: wat about categories formation in the graph...i have added my projects in the array..I dont think so it is correct or not..help me

Comment: @Harifrais this is why you need to be much more specific with your question. I'm afraid I can't read your mind to determine exactly what you want. If you update the question to show exactly what you want I'll happily update this answer for you

Comment: @Harifrais getting the list of projects to use as categories is really easy (see update) but the problem here is as described on your question.... categories in highcharts works by syncing up the series data with the categories and as the number is mismatched your graph wont look as you expect.

Comment: can u help me with sample in the fiddle

Comment: Hi your answer not showing properly..I missed to notice yesterday

Comment: @Harifrais what do you mean it is not showing properly?

Comment: chart data not rendering properly

Comment: @Harifrais did you check the jsfiddle link at the end - I literally got highcharts to work with your data!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea how to parse your data to using in the Highcharts library, no matter how many properties will be in the `data.hours` object.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31tp0mkw/

```
const categories = sampleJson.map(data => data.project);

const getSeriesNames = sampleJson.map(data => {
    for (let i in data.hours) {
        return i
    }
}).filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i);


const series = getSeriesNames.map(name => {
    let output = {
        name: name,
        data: []
    };

    sampleJson.forEach(data => {
        if (data.hours[name]) {
            output.data.push(data.hours[name])
        } else {
            output.data.push(null)
        }
    });
    
    return output
})
```

Comment: Hi your answer not showing properly..I missed to notice yesterday.Can you check once again

Comment: @Harifrais you right, I fixed, by pushing the null values for unknown points.